# How to get VIEWSTATE and EVENTVALIDATION values from asp page in android

Tags: android, asp.net, web-services

I am creating an android app which accesses .asp page. For web form submission I have to send `EVENTVALIDATION` and `VIEWSTATE` values to the server.To my understanding these values differ for each web form control.

So in a page response from the server I am getting the `EVENTVALIDATION` value which I have to send when I make form submission.

```
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/wEWMg....>
```

I have http method which sends post request to the server and gets the response

General code :

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
httppost.addHeader("Cookie","ASP.NET_SessionId="+cookieId+"; path=/");
httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httppost);
response = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());
```

I also noticed that the input `type="hidden"` for the eventvalidate value.

So my question is how can I get `EVENTVALIDATION` value from the response so that I can use it for subsequent form submission at a later stage.

Comment: Yes, you are right. These input values are different for each page each time. They used for storing some information about controls during rendering.

Answer (score 2):

Found a way to get EVENTVALIDATION and VIEWSTATE values from response using JSOUP

```
 Document document=Jsoup.parse(response);
 String viewState=document.select("#__VIEWSTATE").attr("value");
 String eventValidate=document.select("#__EVENTVALIDATION").attr("value");
```